# Why is friction not dissipative in rolling motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, work

We know that non-conservative forces like friction is a dissipative force.

But according to my book when a solid cylinder is rolling down a rough inclined plane of inclination angle $\theta$ the friction is not dissipative. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the work done by friction is converted into rotational kinetic energy of the cylinder, since friction provides the torque to roll down the cylinder.